# Does construction stop after a raid

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans, my friend told me 'If you are upgrading a town hall, and you are raided, it stops and you lose all the resources'. I was wondering if he was telling the truth or not. If anyone can help me, please! I don't want to risk it.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is obviously not telling the truth and i speak from experience.

I currently have my Town Hall being updated from Level 9 to 10 which takes well over a week. it is positioned in a spot so most attackers will aim for it and allow me to loose trophies but my resources are kept safe.

Since I am attacked on a daily basis, the times where the attacker as only been able to steal resources from my Town Hall the results show they have only obtained 1,000 Gold and Elixir, the same amount it has always given up when totally destroyed. while i normally have stored 2,000,000 as i build up for upgrades, if i lost all my resources just because the Town Hall was being upgraded then i wouldn't ever have enough to upgrade by Wizard Towers during an upgrade

Also, as i only check in once a day it being destroyed does not stop the construction since if that was the case then i wouldn't see roughly a day's progress done on my Town Hall Upgrade

Comment: I think when the question states `you lose all the resources`, what they really mean is "all of the resources the Town Hall has to offer" or something to that effect. Not "all of the resources in your village ignoring all limits that attackers normally encounter when raiding resources."